# How to start profile agent in yourkit?

Tags: jmeter, yourkit

How to start profile agent in yourkit. Getting message that I am trying without start the profiler agent when trying to attach jmeter in yourkit.

I don't know how to start the agent, can anyone please help me as early as possible. Trying to attach on windows 11 and locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to profile JMeter using YourKit you need to launch JMeter with [YourKit telemetry enabled](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java-profiler/2023.5/help/agent.jsp) like:

```
java -agentpath:c:\path\to\yourkit\yjpagent.dll -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Another possibility is setting `JVM_ARGS` or `JMETER_OPTS` environment variable to contain `-agentpath:c:\path\to\yourkit\yjpagent.dll` line.

However I don't think you need to profile JMeter itself, it's quite mature product and there are no obvious memory leaks or inefficient algorithms so it should be sufficient to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article